# Dependency is not distributed to Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, mesos, dcos

I'm trying to execute Spark job on Mesos cluster that depends on [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) library, but it keeps failing with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/package$
```

As I understand from [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/submitting-applications.html)

> JARs and files are copied to the working directory for each SparkContext on the executor nodes.
>   ...
>   Users may also include any other dependencies by supplying a comma-delimited list of maven coordinates with --packages.

But it seems that only `pucker-assembly-1.0.jar` task jar is distributed.

I'm running  spark 1.6.1 with scala 2.10.6.
And here's `spark-submit` command I'm executing:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster 
             --master mesos://localhost:57811 
             --conf spark.ssl.noCertVerification=true 
             --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.5.1-s_2.10
             --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.0.1.83,10.0.1.86,10.0.1.85 
             --driver-cores 3 
             --driver-memory 4000M 
             --class SimpleApp 
             https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/pucker-assembly-1.0.jar
             s3n://logs/E1SR85P3DEM3LU.2016-05-05-11.ceaeb015.gz
```

So why isn't `spark-cassandra-connector` distributed to all my spark executers?

Comment: Are you sure it finds the connector?

Comment: What do you mean?
I tried passing connector dependency using `--jars https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.6.0.jar`, and that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct Maven coordinate syntax:

```
--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.6.0
```

See

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10
- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html
- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that seems to not be an issue(and original connector package link actually works as well). The same thing happened when I tried to distribute other packages/jars as well.

Comment: Strange, because that works like a charm on our cluster